# What is the intensity of a wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, visible-light

> "In the single-photon case, the intensity of the wave at any point is proportional to the probability of finding the photon at that point."

I read this in a physics book. What is meant by intensity? For example if we have a wave $\phi(t)=\sin(t)$ is the intensity of the wave at $t$ simply $\sin(t)$? But then what do negative values mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intensity is proportional to the magnitude of the amplitude squared, $|\!\sin t|^2$ in your example. The factor of proportionality depends on the physics context.

Comment: Can you clarify that last sentence a bit? What physics content?

Comment: I mean that "intensity" usually means something like energy density or desnity of something else, and there are then constants that convert then amplitude-squared to that quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding:

$$\phi(t) = \sin{t} $$

That is indeed a wave mathematically, it is difficult to have any sensible physical interpretation in that form.

Presumably, $t$ represents time. With S.I. units, that would be in seconds, and you can't take the sine of "seconds". Say you want to know $\phi(60{\rm\,s})$. That's:

$$ \sin(60) \approx -0.305 $$

What if you want the value at one minute?

$$ \sin(1) \approx 0.841 $$

They don't agree. So, you need a dimensional scale factor with which to scale $t$, say, the period: $T$. If we pick a value, say 3 seconds, then:

$$ \phi = \sin{\big(2\pi\frac t T\big)} $$

That, at 60 seconds we have:

$$ \frac t T = \frac{60\,s}{3\,{\rm s}} = 20 $$

and at one minute, we find:

$$ \frac t T = \frac{1{\rm \,m}}{3\,{\rm m}} =  \frac{1{\rm \,m}}{3\,{\rm m}}\times 60{\,\rm m/s}=20$$

and now the result does not depend on units.

It is customary to use angular frequency:

$$ \omega \equiv \frac{2\pi}{T}\approx 2.09\,{\rm Hz}$$

so that:

$$ \phi(t) = \sin\omega t $$

The sine function's target is also real number, so at this point, $phi$is just a number. It's hard to interpret that as a physical amplitude.

That needs to be included:

$$\phi(t) = A_0\sin{\omega t} $$

where $A_0$ is a dimensional quantity that depends on the physical wave being described.

It could be air pressure in a sound wave, electric field in light or radar. Since the problem, as written, has zero spatial dimensions in the input domain (there is no $x$), one could say it models the displacement of a mass on a spring, and then $A_0$ would have dimensions of length (meters in S.I.). Say:

$$A_0 = 0.2\,{\rm m}$$

One doesn't really talk about the "intensity" of a mass on a spring, but at any time, the potential energy stored in the spring (with constant $k$) is:

$$ E(t) = \frac 1 2 k \phi(t)^2 = \frac 1 2 kA_0^2\sin^2{\omega t}$$

which is always non-negative.